# "ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'apiclient ' "

Tags: python, google-api, google-api-client

I recently tried to view Google Calendar using python . To do that I referred Python Quickstart. I did the steps that were mentioned in the website.
I completed the second step and downloaded the secretclient.json file.
In the terminal I typed in :

```
                   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

as I was instructed in the website.
I ran the python that was on the website and when I compiled I got the error:

> Blockquote
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "quickstart.py", line 2, in 
>       from apiclient import discovery
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient'

The Lines which correspond to the error are :

```
from apiclient import discovery
```

Why is the apiclient module unavailable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you're using a different python version than what the pip installed? For example, if you use python3 to execute the problematic import line, but pip is for python2. Or if you use conda or another python distribution that uses a different path to import the packages from.
You can verify it if you just open from the command line:

```
python
```

then

```
from apiclient import discovery
```

and check if you still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

you can resolve this by going to Script folder of your Python installation directory and running from there 
e.g.

```
cd D:\Python27\Scripts\
python
from apiclient import discovery
```

Mainly this issue arises when u have more than one python installation , as noob have suggested

Comment: This happened to me just now with my MVC App and I'm looking for a solution.